# input and arrays

Tags: matlab

I want to know how to store input values in an array in MATLAB by asking the question only one time, like this output

Enter values for mass (mo): [1 2 3 4 5]

Comment: So what have you tried so far already?

Answer (score 5):

The default behavior of [INPUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html) will allow you to enter a vector, provided you include the square brackets when typing your input:

```
>> vec = input('Enter values for mass (mo): ');  %# Ask for input
Enter values for mass (mo): [1 2 3 4 5]          %# Enter [1 2 3 4 5]
>> vec                                           %# Display vec

vec =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

This behavior may not be obvious, as you may be used to entering only scalar values and strings with [INPUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html). You have to pay special attention to this part of the documentation (emphasis added):

> `evalResponse = input(prompt)` displays
>   the `prompt` string on the screen, waits
>   for input from the keyboard, **evaluates
>   any expressions in the input,** and
>   returns the value in `evalResponse`. To
>   evaluate expressions, the `input`
>   function accesses variables in the
>   current workspace.

This means you could even enter input like this:

```
Enter values for mass (mo): [1*8 2+9 zeros(1,3) pi]
>> vec

vec =

    8.0000   11.0000         0         0         0    3.1416
```

Answer (score 3):

[gnovice's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873148/input-and-arrays/5873219#5873219) & [Peter R.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873148/input-and-arrays/5873250#5873250) answers address your question. However, I thought I'd mention why using evaluated responses for applications where where *you're not the end user* is a terrible idea.

While the feature is certainly useful, as demonstrated by gnovice, it also evaluates system calls!

```
Enter values for mass: system('echo "hello world" ')
hello world
```

That's a response from my OS. `vec` just stores the exit return value from the function. You can pretty much do anything, including

```
Enter values for mass: system('rm -rf /')
```

which will simply erase the entire drive, if running as super user. Granting users an entry to your OS is simply a bad, bad idea, and I mention this, because I've seen several science kiosks, where they have some small program written in MATLAB to illustrate some concept and and use `input` to request values from the users (random folks strolling by). Perhaps not everyone thinks like me, so they haven't had trouble so far :). However, this is just like [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and every argument that can be made for sanitizing databases, can be applied here too.

The way around in this case, is to use `input` with an optional second input argument, as

```
vec=input('Enter values for mass: ','s');
```

This stores the *unevaluated* string to the variable `vec`, and you can then check for malicious content before evaluating it (or only allow a whitelisted set of functions & characters).

```
Enter values for mass: system('echo "hello world" ')
>> vec

vec =

system('echo "hello world" ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = input(‘Enter values for mass (mo): ’);
```